# Is there any difference between native-base <View/> and react-native <View/>?

Tags: react-native, native

I know native-base in a wrapper on react-native library but there are some components which we can import from react-native as well as from native-base also eg., View, Text, etc., Is there any difference between these two imported components. I am new to react native just want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native Base uses the original react native view and extends it a little bit.

Here is the full code from native base' view:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { View, ViewPropTypes } from "react-native";
import { connectStyle } from "native-base-shoutem-theme";
import mapPropsToStyleNames from "../utils/mapPropsToStyleNames";

class ViewNB extends Component {
  render() {
    return <View ref={c => (this._root = c)} {...this.props} />;
  }
}

ViewNB.propTypes = {
  ...ViewPropTypes,
  style: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.object,
    PropTypes.number,
    PropTypes.array
  ])
};

const StyledViewNB = connectStyle(
  "NativeBase.ViewNB",
  {},
  mapPropsToStyleNames
)(ViewNB);
export { StyledViewNB as ViewNB };
```

Source: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/master/src/basic/View.js

Comment: So in short for every other (Text etc.,) component which is available in both libraries the native base uses core one from react-native and extend it with some extra properties Is that correct?

Comment: @AkshaykumarDigrase I don't know, but you can check all the components by yourself if you are checking native base's github: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/master/src

Comment: @AkshaykumarDigrase if my answer was helpful and answered your question, please mark it as accepted. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I diagnosed more in this and got chain react and kitchen slink which gives more clarity about every component

> https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase